# Custom loadView and container views

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have an abstract base class for `UIViewController` that all the controllers in my application inherit from. I also have a subclass of `UIView` (`View`), that adds a few additional desired properties, reactive cocoa awesomeness among them. Now in my custom view controller class, I want to override `loadView` and do this:

```
override func loadView() {
    let customView = View(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.view = customView
}
```

and then I have a property `rac_view`:

```
var rac_view: View {
    return self.view as? View ?? View()
}
```

so that all subclasses of my view controller class can have immediate access to the `View` property without having to perform additional casting themselves.

It all works great until I override `loadView`. As soon as I do, I get a crash on application startup:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'containerView is required.'
```

In my storyboard, my initial view controller has several container views with embedded segues to other view controllers that inherit from my abstract base class. For some reason, overriding `loadView` and setting my own custom view throws a wrench in the works when it comes to container views, and I'm not sure why.

Has anyone seen or experienced something like this before?

Comment: It could be because you're assigning self.view to two different things, once to custom view and the other to rac_view. Have you tried a different initializer other than loadView as well?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason was despite setting a custom view in `loadView`, in my storyboard my view controller's views were of type `UIView`, not `View`. In fact, I didn't need to override `loadView` at all, just set the view property in the storyboard to my custom class.